# MYSQL SELECT LIKE "masks"

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm using a field in a table to hold information about varios checkboxes (60).

The field is parsed to a string to something like this

```
"0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,..."
```

Now I want to make a search using a similar string to match the fields. I.e.

```
"?,?,1,?,?,1,..."
```

where the "?" means that it must be 0 or 1 (doesn't matter), but the "1" must match.

As i've seen the '%' is somewhat innapropriate for this case, don't?

Obviosly both strings have the same lenght.

Suggestions?

Comment: Ugh, I shiver to think of 60 checkboxes :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the underscore (_) character to match a single character in the mask.

Taken from [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

Answer (score -1):

where `column_name REGEXP "^.*,.*,.*,1,.*,1$"`

Please try to replace .* instead of ? by using regexp

Comment: As to "why the downvote?", see: https://dbfiddle.uk/3hAeRrN6

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).